# Avoiding ref to be passed to the parent component: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I am having a file uploader which is a child component. The state of the files are being maintained in tha App component. I am trying to mock, the upload and failure cases inside App component itself using `setInterval`. But I am using passing a ref from the child component to the parent callback, just so that I get the latest upload status of a file inside setTimeout. Implementation works just fine, Is there someway where I can do all this, without passing down any ref to the parent component inside callback?

I am able to successfully mock the completion and failure. In the below sandbox, I am hardcoding the file name to "1.txt" so that uploads fail just for that.

Note: Its ok if I have to create any ref's inside App, I just dont want the ref to be part of `onFileUpload` callback when passed to the App component

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/updated-file-upload-forked-k59xgo

Inside File Upload

```
 const timerRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file.active && !file.uploadError) {
      onFileUpload(file, timerRef);
    }
  }, [file.active, file, onFileUpload]);
```

Inside App

```
 const onFileUpload = (
    selectedFile: FileType,
    uploadRef: React.MutableRefObject<
      ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined
    >
  ) => {
    pollRef.current = selectedFile;
    if (!uploadRef.current) {
      uploadRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        if (
          pollRef.current?.uploadStatus === 100 ||
          pollRef.current?.uploadError
        ) {
          clearInterval(uploadRef.current);
        }
        const diff: number = Math.random() * 15;
        let currentProgess: number = pollRef.current?.uploadStatus as number;
        setSelectedFiles((prevState: FileType[]) => {
          return prevState.map((currentFile: FileType) => {
            const {
              file: { name: currentFileName },
              uploadStatus: currentFileUploadStatus
            } = currentFile;
            if (currentFileName === selectedFile.file.name) {
              if (
                selectedFile.file.name === "1.pdf" &&
                currentFileUploadStatus > 40
              ) {
                clearInterval(uploadRef.current);
                return {
                  ...currentFile,
                  uploadStatus: 0,
                  isActive: true,
                  uploadError: "Upload Error"
                };
              }
              currentProgess = Math.min(currentFileUploadStatus + diff, 100);
              return {
                ...currentFile,
                uploadStatus: currentProgess
              };
            } else return currentFile;
          });
        });
        return currentProgess;
      }, 60 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 100);
    }
  };
```

Comment: If a child component is calling a function to pass data back up to the parent, then *something* needs to be passed down from parent component to child component. Since you didn't include a [mcve] of the parent ***or*** child component it's a bit unclear what you are asking for help with specifically in relation to these two components.

Comment: @DrewReese Sandbox is in the question. Yes I get that, but what I mean is, I don't want to pass the ref from the child.

Comment: The post still needs to possess a self-contained [mcve]. External links can die at any moment. So in the sandbox of yours, `App` is the "parent" component and `Upload` is the "child"? And what exactly are you trying to change here? Can you clarify what the issue is you are trying to solve?

Comment: @DrewReese I am going to make this Uploader as a standalone component. Now in order to just mock uploading part, I have created a interval inside parent. Tomorrow this is going to get replaced by an API. So that time, passing this timer related ref from child will not make any sense.

Comment: @DrewReese yes that's right. App is parent that handles file upload api. Rest components deal with selection deletion of files.

Answer (score 0):

You already use the file name as key for React.

```
<ListItem key={file.file.name} className={"file-name"}>
```

You could also use it as a key for the timeouts.

Effectively, that's what already happens. You rely on React rendering your unique component to get the right timeout reference.

This allows you to remove `uploadRef`, also from the `UploadFile` component as it was only used for this timeout.

```
const fileIntervals = useRef({});
const onFileUpload = ( selectedFile: FileType ) => {
  // ...
  const { name } = selectedFile;
  if (fileIntervals.current[name]) {
    return;
  }
  fileIntervals.current[name] = setInterval( // ...
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/updated-file-upload-parent-forked-jhko3m?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Please check the sandbox. Delete and reuploading failed file isnt triggering any progress. Also deleted file, if reuploading again, isnt getting added. I guess with your ref object timer is not getting cleared

Comment: This example code is purely illustrative, so yes you might need to adapt your implementation a bit more.

Comment: I recommend, before proceeding, to refactor this code. For example, try to avoid all your logic being inside one big if statement, with many levels. It naturally causes you to get confused. Try also to avoid using `useEffect` for state management altogether. It surely causes a ton of issues by itself and is not how `useEffect` is intended to be used.

Comment: alright, thanks, Just a beginner to react.  Been stuck here for quite some days, may be your guidance could help. Thats the reason,  asked for attention by raising bounty.